# Why does groupBy() work but Count() does not in laravel eloquent model function?

Tags: laravel, group-by, eloquent, count

I need to get counts of all the records based on `belongsToMany` relationship. normally I can use `groupBy()` in a function inside the model. but if I use `count()` or `withCount()` inside a model function, i get the error as followed:

function code:

```php
public function TaskCount(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->count();
}
```

Error message:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on int in file /Users/dragonar/Dev/iyw/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php on line 560
```

If I do the following...

```php
public function TaskCount(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->Count();
}

//expected record is 4(int)

//output is 4(array) user records.
```

...it gives me data but like 4 records of the user instead of a number 4. The user data is useless. The only thing needed is `totalCount` for those records.

Answer (score 2):

Relationship methods have to return Relation type objects. You are returning the result of a query, `count()` returns a number not the Relation object / Builder. Remove the `count` from that statement you are returning. Renamed the relationship `tasks` here.

```
public function tasks() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    // this returns a Relation type object a BelongsToMany object
}
```

Where you need to use that relationship you can then use `count`:

```
$something->tasks()->count();
```

Or you can load the count of the relationship using `loadCount`:

```
$something->loadCount('tasks');
$something->tasks_count;
```

Or via eager loading for a collection:

```
$results = Something::withCount('tasks')->get();

foreach ($results as $model) {
    echo $model->tasks_count;
}
```

If you really wanted to you could create an accessor to get the count as well, you just may want to avoid the N+1 issue by preloading the relationship and using the dynamic property to access it in the accessor.

These relation objects are Builders. When you called `groupBy` on it previously that is returning the Builder, it isn't executing the query. You can add where conditions and order by statements because they are just building the query, not executing it, they return the builder you are calling the method on.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) `withCount` `loadCount`

Comment: what if i have `User::with['Tasks','Task.Details']->whereUserId($uid);` you see i have to go one level more deep that is `Task.Details'.

Comment: yes, that gives me the total amount/count but not by groupBy clause added like if I have 3 tasks done for a user in 2 days, the number of days I user took for the task was 2 but as i have 3 records for the same in db, it gives me 3 days as total which is the only issue i have right now.

Comment: your original issue of the relation method is fixed ... but i think you have expectations that aren't correct for how all of this stuff works

Answer (score 0):

Why not use: `Task::all()->count();` ?

Comment: I can't user `Task::all()->count` as its for the current user or user by id. so what i am currently doing is. `User::with(['Task', 'Task.TotalCount' => function($q) use ($uid) {
            $r = $q->whereUserId($uid);
        }])->whereId($uid)->first();`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `withCount` method while calling relation like this

```
User::withCount('images')->get();
```

Comment: I can't use with count as it's not giving me the desire details.

Comment: what I mean is that withCount() gives me total of all records, but does not filter with groupby.

Comment: @princeoo7 can you please add more code so i can understand the whole situation?

Answer (score -1):

You can add get the data and just count it.

```
public function TaskCount(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->get()->count();
}
```

You can call it like

```
$taskCount = $task->TaskCount();
```

Comment: Not working for me as it gives me `Call to a member function getRelationExistenceCountQuery() on int` error